# Meteor asynchronous log in issue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, authentication

I built an app using meteor and encountered an issue with logging in. I have an admin page  that can only be accessible by an admin. The app checks the user object to see if the `isAdmin` attribute is true or false. If it is false, the app will render an access denied page. However, when go to the admin page with an account where `isAdmin` is true, the access denied page flickers very briefly before taking me to the admin page. Can someone help? I think the issue has something to do with Meteor's asynchronous nature. Here is my admin controller which has the routing logic:

```
adminController = RouteController.extend({
waitOn: function () { 
    Meteor.subscribe('adminView');
},
onBeforeAction: function () {
    var currUserId = Meteor.userId();
    var currUser = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: currUserId});
    if (!currUser.isAdmin) {
        this.render('accessDenied2');
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if there's a use in the first place. Then the page won't display anything until the user's data is availible:

```
onBeforeAction: function () {
    var currUser = Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId());
    if(currUser) {
        if (!currUser.isAdmin) {
            this.render('accessDenied2');
        } else {
            this.next();
        }
    }
}
```